# pysnmp generate Trap to target in non-default vrf

Tags: net-snmp, pysnmp, snmp-trap

I am trying to use `pysnmp sendNotification()` to generate a trap on Debian 9. It works fine when my trap target is in default VRF but when the target is not in the default VRF it fails silently.

I found that the Perl library for SNMP trap generation works in the same scenario because it depends on a "trap2link" statement in `/etc/snmp/snmpd.conf` which specifies `-n vrf`. I thought the `pysnmp` client might also be able to take advantage of `trap2link` statements but it does not appear to be the case.

I have searched thoroughly for all references to `pysnmp+vrf+trap2link` and combinations thereof with no success. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I am not sure what VRF is in the context of SNMP... I am guessing that may be `-n vrf` refers to SNMP ContextName. Could you please publish the code which fails?

Comment: It is the Virtual Routing and Forwarding table in which the IP address of the SNMP target resolves. The code snippet is just a standard sendNotification()    errorIndication, errorStatus, errorIndex, varBinds = next(
        sendNotification(
            Engine,
            CommunityData(target['community']),
            UdpTransportTarget((target['ip'], target['port'])),
            Context,
            'trap',

Comment: Further to my previous comment, the SNMP target in the default routing table resolves without problems but for non-default routing tables, I could not find a way to specify this. I will try ContextName. Thanks.